# Redimensionar el calendario de un DateTimePicker WinForm

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

He realizado una serie de formularios en winform que el usuario puede redimensionar y a su gusto, no he tenido ningún problema en redimensionar los distintos controles que hay en cada formulario, salvo con el datetimepicker, y mas concretamente con el calendario desplegable. El control cambia de tamaño pero el calendario desplegable siempre queda en el mismo tamaño

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mirando la clase DateTimePicker de c# he encontrado:

```
    public class DateTimePicker : Control 
    // Resumen:
    //     Obtiene o establece el estilo de fuente que se aplica al calendario.
    //
    // Devuelve:
    //     System.Drawing.Font que representa el estilo de fuente que se aplica al calendario.

    public Font CalendarFont { get; set; }
```

Por lo que he pensado que aumentando la fuente q viene por defecto aumentaria el tamaño pero no ha cambiado nada:

```
    ((DateTimePicker)control).CalendarFont = new Font("serif", 16f, f.Style, ((Byte)(0)));
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crea un `UserControl` que extienda de `DateTimePicker` y en este modifica su código para que actúe como necesitas que lo haga.

Hay una propiedad [`CalendarFont`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.calendarfont?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) que es responsable de obtener / establecer la fuente del calendario desplegable. Pero el valor se aplicará solo cuando los estilos visuales estén deshabilitados.

Puede manejar el evento `DropDown` de `DateTimePicker` y encontrar el `MonthCalendar` de la lista desplegable. Luego deshabilite los Estilos visuales solo para ese control. Luego recalcule el tamaño requerido del control y configure el tamaño del menú desplegable en función del tamaño mínimo requerido del calendario.

Luego, el control mostrará un menú desplegable con la fuente que especificó en la propiedad [`CalendarFont`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.calendarfont?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8):

[image]

**Código**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyDateTimePicker : DateTimePicker
{
    private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    private const int DTM_First = 0x1000;
    private const int DTM_GETMONTHCAL = DTM_First + 8;
    private const int MCM_GETMINREQRECT = DTM_First + 9;

    [DllImport("uxtheme.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, string appName, string idList);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, ref RECT lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
    int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT { public int L, T, R, B; }
    protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        var hwndCalendar = SendMessage(this.Handle, DTM_GETMONTHCAL, 0, 0);
        SetWindowTheme(hwndCalendar, string.Empty, string.Empty);
        var r = new RECT();
        SendMessage(hwndCalendar, MCM_GETMINREQRECT, 0, ref r);
        var hwndDropDown = GetParent(hwndCalendar);
        SetWindowPos(hwndDropDown, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0,
            r.R - r.L + 6, r.B - r.T + 6, SWP_NOMOVE);
        base.OnDropDown(eventargs);
    }
}
```

**Referencia:**
SO Inglés

> [Is it possible to increase size of calendar popup in winform?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48031655/8933039)
>
> Otro enlace que puede ser de utilidad: [Establecer el tamaño del calendario al anular DateTimePicker para agregar números de semana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563851/8933039)

---

*¿Como puedo deshabilitar el estilo visual de un control concreto?*

No se si funcione para todos los controles pero puedes hacer algo como esto, usar `SetWindowTheme` en un control:

```
[DllImport("uxtheme", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public extern static Int32 SetWindowTheme (IntPtr hWnd, 
              String textSubAppName, String textSubIdList);

tuControl.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
SetWindowTheme(tuControl.Handle, "", "");
```

> [Artículo original sobre esto en CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26488/How-to-Disable-Windows-Themes-Using-uxtheme-dll-an)

Comment: ¿Como puedo deshabilitar el estilo visual de un control concreto?. La unica forma que he encoontrado es deshabilitando la de todos los controles de la aplicación: file ->  Program.cs   //Application.EnableVisualStyles();

Comment: @miajiru revisa la edición de mi respuesta a ver si te funciona eso...